# SQLSTATE[HY000]:General error: 1364 Field 'date_project_start' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

После наполнения данными ,и нажатия на кнопку отправить происходит данная ошибка .
Файл ProjectController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App;
use App\Project;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $project = App\Project::all();
        return view('project.main', compact('project'));
    }
    public function show($id) {
        $projects = App\Project::find($id);
        return view('project.full', compact('projects'));
    }
    public function create() {
        return view('project.add');
    }
    public function store()
    {
        $input = Request::all();

        Project::create($input);

        return redirect('project');
    }

}
```

Но колонок update_at, create_at. у меня нету и не было . Не где их упоминания нету вообще !
Но это только если я создаю через сайт, если делаю все через PMA, то все хорошо, все данные выводятся без ошибок и каких либо заморочек !

Схема таблицы для миграции.

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('zadacha');
            $table->date('date_project_start');
            $table->date('date_project_end');
            $table->date('date_proektirovanie_start');
            $table->date('date_proektirovanie_end');
            $table->date('date_snabjenie_start');
            $table->date('date_snabjenie_end');
            $table->date('date_proizvodstvo_start');
            $table->date('date_proizvodstvo_end');
        });
```

Comment: Причем тут update_at и create_at??? В ошибку переведите свою - поле `date_project_start` не имеет значения по умолчанию

Comment: Но какое значение он должен иметь если его не должно там быть ? Это поле для заполнения даты (Добавил миграцию)

Comment: Понял. Поля почему то обязательные к заполнению, а возможно ли сделать их не обязательными для заполнения ?

Comment: `->nullable()` так?

Answer (score 1):

Если Ваше поле может содержать "пустое значение" вы должны сказать об этом базе данных, в `laravel` это происходит так:

```php
  // ...
  $table->date('date_project_start')->nullable();
  // ...
```

Тогда, если значение не задано(или задано `null`), база данных будет использовать NULL. Вы так же можете использовать метод `->default($val);`, чтобы задать какое-то определенное значение. Однако не стоит путать `null` со значением, `null` это `null`, оно не равно пустой строке или `0`.